# A question regarding holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $D=\{z:\vert z\vert\leq 1\}$ such that $f(\frac{1}{2})=0$ and $f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$. Then which of the following is/are true?

1. $\vert f^{'}(0)\vert\leq \frac{3}{4}$
2. $\vert f^{'}(\frac{1}{2})\vert\leq \frac{4}{3}$
3. $\vert f^{'}(0)\vert\leq \frac{3}{4}$ and $\vert f^{'}(\frac{1}{2})\vert\leq \frac{4}{3}$
4. $f(z)=z$ for $z\in D$

Option 4 is definitely wrong as $f(0)=0\neq \frac{1}{2}$. But how to check other options?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Apply the [Schwarz—Pick lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem).

*Solution:*

> Schwarz—Pick says $\dfrac{\left|f'(z)\right|}{1-\left|f(z)\right|^2} \le \dfrac{1}{1-\left|z\right|^2}$.  Apply this to $z=0$ and $z=1/2$ and get answer (3).

Comment: Is this enough to answer the whole question though?

Comment: @hjhjhj57, you're right. It's simpler, actually. See my edited answer. Thanks.